# UE4: Error Adding C++ class - ClassName.generated.h - Changes to generated code are not allowed

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm trying to add a C++ class to my Blueprints project in Unreal Engine 4.16.1. But every time I try it gives me an error when trying to create the `ClassName.generated.h` file. It then creates a `ClassName.generated.h.conflict` file instead.

The error I'm getting is "Changes to generated code are not allowed":

```
CompilerResultsLog: Info ERROR: 'D:/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyActor.generated.h': Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyActor.generated.h.conflict'
```

All I have done is right clicked the content browser, clicked `New C++ Class` and then select any class type and create it. I then get a compile error immediately. I haven't made any changes to code as the error suggests.

Here is the full output log in case I've missed something:

```
LogPlatformFile: Not using cached read wrapper
LogInit : Display: RandInit(-1380375261) SRandInit(-1380375261).
LogTaskGraph : Started task graph with 5 named threads and 8 total threads with 1 sets of task threads.
LogStats : Stats thread started at 0.074413
LogInit : Using libcurl 7.47.1
LogInit : -built for x86_64 - pc - win32
LogInit : -supports SSL with OpenSSL / 1.0.2g
LogInit : -supports HTTP deflate(compression) using libz 1.2.8
LogInit : -other features :
LogInit:      CURL_VERSION_SSL
LogInit : CURL_VERSION_LIBZ
LogInit : CURL_VERSION_IPV6
LogInit : CURL_VERSION_ASYNCHDNS
LogInit : CURL_VERSION_LARGEFILE
LogInit : CURL_VERSION_IDN
LogInit : CurlRequestOptions(configurable via config and command line) :
LogInit : -bVerifyPeer = false - Libcurl will NOT verify peer certificate
LogInit : -bUseHttpProxy = false - Libcurl will NOT use HTTP proxy
LogInit : -bDontReuseConnections = false - Libcurl will reuse connections
LogInit : -CertBundlePath = nullptr - Libcurl will use whatever was configured at build time.
LogInit : Build : ++UE4 + Release - 4.16 - CL - 3466753
LogInit : Engine Version : 4.16.1 - 3466753++ + UE4 + Release - 4.16
LogInit : Compatible Engine Version : 4.16.0 - 3452394++ + UE4 + Release - 4.16
LogInit : Net CL : 3452394
LogDevObjectVersion : Number of dev versions registered : 16
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Blueprints(B0D832E4 - 1F89 - 4F0D - ACCF - 7EB736FD4AA2) : 9
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Build(E1C64328 - A22C - 4D53 - A36C - 8E866417BD8C) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Core(375EC13C - 06E4 - 48FB - B500 - 84F0262A717E) : 2
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Editor(E4B068ED - F494 - 42E9 - A231 - DA0B2E46BB41) : 17
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Framework(CFFC743F - 43B0 - 4480 - 9391 - 14DF171D2073) : 23
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Mobile(B02B49B5 - BB20 - 44E9 - A304 - 32B752E40360) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Networking(A4E4105C - 59A1 - 49B5 - A7C5 - 40C4547EDFEE) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Online(39C831C9 - 5AE6 - 47DC - 9A44 - 9C173E1C8E7C) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Physics(78F01B33 - EBEA - 4F98 - B9B4 - 84EACCB95AA2) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Platform(6631380F - 2D4D - 43E0 - 8009 - CF276956A95A) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Rendering(12F88B9F - 8875 - 4AFC - A67C - D90C383ABD29) : 15
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - Sequencer(7B5AE74C - D270 - 4C10 - A958 - 57980B212A5A) : 4
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - VR(D7296918 - 1DD6 - 4BDD - 9DE2 - 64A83CC13884) : 0
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - LoadTimes(C2A15278 - BFE7 - 4AFE - 6C17 - 90FF531DF755) : 1
LogDevObjectVersion : Private - Geometry(6EACA3D4 - 40EC - 4CC1 - B786 - 8BED09428FC5) : 1
LogDevObjectVersion : Dev - AnimPhys(29E575DD - E0A3 - 4627 - 9D10 - D276232CDCEA) : 3
LogInit : Compiled(64 - bit) : May 31 2017 02 : 03 : 30
LogInit : Compiled with Visual C++ : 19.00.24215.01
LogInit : Build Configuration : Development
LogInit : Branch Name : ++UE4 + Release - 4.16
LogInit : Command line : -EpicPortal
LogInit : Base directory : D: / Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / Win64 /
LogInit : Installed Engine Build : 1
LogInit : Presizing for max 8388607 objects, including 0 objects not considered by GC, pre - allocating 0 bytes for permanent pool.
LogInit : Object subsystem initialized
LogInit : Selected Device Profile : [Windows]
LogInit : Applying CVar settings loaded from the selected device profile : [Windows]
LogInit : Computer : DESKTOP - P8AFSV1
LogInit : User: Removed
LogInit : CPU Page size = 4096, Cores = 4
LogInit : High frequency timer resolution = 3.914070 MHz
LogMemory : Memory total : Physical = 31.9GB(32GB approx)
LogMemory : Platform Memory Stats for Windows
LogMemory : Process Physical Memory : 274.02 MB used, 274.02 MB peak
LogMemory : Process Virtual Memory : 260.82 MB used, 260.82 MB peak
LogMemory : Physical Memory : 6733.64 MB used, 25974.71 MB free, 32708.35 MB total
LogMemory : Virtual Memory : 638.46 MB used, 25974.71 MB free, 134217728.00 MB total
LogInit : Using OS detected language(en - GB).
LogInit : Using OS detected locale(en - GB).
LogTextLocalizationManager : No specific localization for 'en-GB' exists, so the 'en' localization will be used.
LogD3D11RHI : D3D11 adapters :
LogD3D11RHI:    0. 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080' (Feature Level 11_0)
LogD3D11RHI : 8110 / 0 / 16354 MB DedicatedVideo / DedicatedSystem / SharedSystem, Outputs : 2, VendorId : 0x10de
LogD3D11RHI : 1. 'Microsoft Basic Render Driver' (Feature Level 11_0)
LogD3D11RHI : 0 / 0 / 16354 MB DedicatedVideo / DedicatedSystem / SharedSystem, Outputs : 0, VendorId : 0x1414
LogD3D11RHI : Chosen D3D11 Adapter : 0
LogD3D11RHI : Creating new Direct3DDevice
LogD3D11RHI : GPU DeviceId : 0x1b80 (for the marketing name, search the web for "GPU Device Id")
LogWindows : EnumDisplayDevices :
LogWindows : 0. 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080' (P : 1 D : 1)
LogWindows : 1. 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080' (P : 0 D : 1)
LogWindows : 2. 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080' (P : 0 D : 0)
LogWindows : 3. 'NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080' (P : 0 D : 0)
LogWindows : DebugString : FoundDriverCount : 4
LogD3D11RHI : Adapter Name : NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080
LogD3D11RHI : Driver Version : 382.05 (internal:22.21.13.8205, unified : 382.05)
LogD3D11RHI : Driver Date : 5 - 1 - 2017
LogRHI : Texture pool is 1361 MB(70 % of 1945 MB)
LogD3D11RHI : Async texture creation enabled
LogD3D11RHI : GPU Timing Frequency : 1000.000000 (Debug : 2 1)
LogShaderCompilers : Guid format shader working directory is - 26 characters bigger than the processId version(.. / .. / .. / .. / .. / .. / Unreal Projects / SurvivalProject / Intermediate / Shaders / WorkingDirectory / 15808 / ).
LogShaderCompilers : Cleaned the shader compiler working directory 'C:/Users/Removed/AppData/Local/Temp/UnrealShaderWorkingDir/7355AADD42AC9B10A1202984750D1FB6/'.
LogShaderCompilers : Display : Using Local Shader Compiler.
LogTemp : Display : Loaded TP AllDesktopTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP MacClientTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP MacNoEditorTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP MacServerTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP MacTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP WindowsClientTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP WindowsNoEditorTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP WindowsServerTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP WindowsTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP AndroidTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_ASTCTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_ATCTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_DXTTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_ETC1TargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_ETC2TargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_MultiTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP Android_PVRTCTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP HTML5TargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP IOSTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP TVOSTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP LinuxClientTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP LinuxNoEditorTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP LinuxServerTargetPlatform
LogTemp : Display: Loaded TP LinuxTargetPlatform
LogTargetPlatformManager : Display: Building Assets For Windows
LogDerivedDataCache : Display: Max Cache Size : 512 MB
LogDerivedDataCache : Loaded boot cache 0.07s 90MB C : / Users / Removed / AppData / Local / UnrealEngine / 4.16 / DerivedDataCache / Boot.ddc.
LogDerivedDataCache : Display : Loaded Boot cache : C: / Users / Removed / AppData / Local / UnrealEngine / 4.16 / DerivedDataCache / Boot.ddc
LogDerivedDataCache : FDerivedDataBackendGraph:  Pak pak cache file .. / .. / .. / .. / .. / .. / Users / Removed / Documents / Unreal Projects / SurvivalProject / DerivedDataCache / DDC.ddp not found, will not use a pak cache.
LogDerivedDataCache : Unable to find inner node Pak for hierarchical cache Hierarchy.
LogDerivedDataCache : FDerivedDataBackendGraph : CompressedPak pak cache file .. / .. / .. / .. / .. / .. / Users / Removed / Documents / Unreal Projects / SurvivalProject / DerivedDataCache / Compressed.ddp not found, will not use a pak cache.
LogDerivedDataCache : Unable to find inner node CompressedPak for hierarchical cache Hierarchy.
LogDerivedDataCache : Display : Pak cache opened for reading .. / .. / .. / Engine / DerivedDataCache / Compressed.ddp.
LogDerivedDataCache : Using Local data cache path C : / Users / Removed / AppData / Local / UnrealEngine / Common / DerivedDataCache : Writable
LogMaterial : Verifying Global Shaders for PCD3D_SM5
LogSlate : Using Freetype 2.6.0
LogSlate : SlateFontCache - WITH_FREETYPE : 1, WITH_HARFBUZZ : 1
LogSlate : SlateFontCache - WITH_FREETYPE : 1, WITH_HARFBUZZ : 1
LogInit : Selected Device Profile : [Windows]
LogContentStreaming : Texture pool size is 0.00 MB
LogMeshUtilities : Using QuadricMeshReduction for automatic static mesh reduction
LogSimplygon : Simplygon DLL not present - disabling.
LogMeshUtilities : Using SimplygonSwarm for distributed automatic mesh merging
LogMeshUtilities : No automatic skeletal mesh reduction module available
LogMeshUtilities : No automatic mesh merging module available
LogNetVersion : SurvivalProject, NetCL : 3452394, EngineNetVer : 2, GameNetVer : 0 (Checksum : 3130795249)
LogAssetRegistry : FAssetRegistry took 0.0247 seconds to start up
LogPackageLocalizationCache : Processed 4 localized package path(s) for 2 prioritized culture(s) in 0.031140 seconds
LogUObjectArray : 34194 objects as part of root set at end of initial load.
LogUObjectAllocator : 7260416 out of 0 bytes used by permanent object pool.
LogUObjectArray : CloseDisregardForGC : 0 / 0 objects in disregard for GC pool
LogInit : WinSock: version 1.1 (2.2), MaxSocks = 32767, MaxUdp = 65467
LogTcpMessaging : Initializing TcpMessaging bridge
LogUdpMessaging : Initializing bridge on interface 0.0.0.0 :0 to multicast group 230.0.0.1 : 6666.
LogMaterial : Uniform references updated for custom material expression Custom.
SourceControl : Info Source control is disabled
SourceControl : Info Source control is disabled
SourceControl : Info Source control is disabled
SourceControl : Info Source control is disabled
LogAndroidPermission : UAndroidPermissionCallbackProxy::GetInstance
LogEngine : Initializing Engine...
LogHMD : Failed to initialize OpenVR with code 110
LogStats : UGameplayTagsManager::ConstructGameplayTagTree : Construct from data asset - 0.000 s
LogStats : UGameplayTagsManager::ConstructGameplayTagTree : GameplayTagTreeChangedEvent.Broadcast - 0.000 s
LogAIModule : Creating AISystem for world Untitled
LogInit : XAudio2 using 'Speakers (Logitech G933 Gaming Headset)' : 6 channels at 48 kHz using 16 bits per sample(channel mask 0x3f)
LogInit : FAudioDevice initialized.
LogDerivedDataCache : Saved boot cache 0.03s 90MB C : / Users / Removed / AppData / Local / UnrealEngine / 4.16 / DerivedDataCache / Boot.ddc.
LogInit : Texture streaming : Enabled
LogEngineSessionManager : EngineSessionManager initialized
LogInit : Transaction tracking system initialized
BlueprintLog : New page : Editor Load
LocalizationService : Info Localization service is disabled
LogCook : Display: Max memory allowance for cook 16384mb min free memory 0mb
LogCook : Display: Mobile HDR setting 1
LogFileCache : Scanning file cache for directory 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Content/' took 0.01s
SourceControl : Info Source control is disabled
Cmd : MAP LOAD FILE = "../../../../../../Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Content/Maps/Map1.umap" TEMPLATE = 0 SHOWPROGRESS = 1 FEATURELEVEL = 3
LightingResults : New page : Lighting Build
MapCheck : New page : Map Check
LightingResults : New page : Lighting Build
LogPhysics : Warning: FDerivedDataPhysXCooker::BuildTriMesh : Triangle data from '/Game/Maps/Map1.Map1:PersistentLevel.ModelComponent_9' invalid(2566 verts, 0 indices).
LogAIModule : Creating AISystem for world Map1
LogEditorServer : Finished looking for orphan Actors(0.000 secs)
Cmd : MAP CHECKDEP NOCLEARLOG
MapCheck : Info Map check complete : 0 Error(s), 0 Warning(s), took 27.034ms to complete.
LogFileHelpers : Loading map 'Map1' took 0.546
LogCollectionManager : Loaded 0 collections in 0.000657 seconds
LogFileCache : Scanning file cache for directory 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Saved/Collections/' took 0.01s
LogFileCache : Scanning file cache for directory 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Content/Developers/DanielandNatalie/Collections/' took 0.01s
LogFileCache : Scanning file cache for directory 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Content/Collections/' took 0.01s
LogCollectionManager : Rebuilt the GUID cache for 0 collections in 0.000001 seconds
LogContentBrowser : Native class hierarchy populated in 0.0070 seconds.Added 2329 classes and 491 folders.
LogContentBrowser : Native class hierarchy updated for 'WidgetCarousel' in 0.0008 seconds.Added 0 classes and 0 folders.
LogContentBrowser : Native class hierarchy updated for 'AddContentDialog' in 0.0008 seconds.Added 0 classes and 0 folders.
LogContentBrowser : Native class hierarchy updated for 'SceneOutliner' in 0.0008 seconds.Added 1 classes and 2 folders.
LogCrashTracker : Crashtracker disabled due to settings.
LogSlate : Took 0.000113 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf' (155K)
LogSlate : Took 0.000158 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf' (160K)
LogSlate : Took 0.000482 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Editor/Slate/Fonts/FontAwesome.ttf' (139K)
LogRenderer : Reallocating scene render targets to support 1056x556 NumSamples 1 (Frame : 1).
LogUObjectGlobals : Warning : Failed to find object 'Class None.'
LogContentBrowser : Native class hierarchy updated for 'HierarchicalLODOutliner' in 0.0014 seconds.Added 1 classes and 2 folders.
LogLoad : (Engine Initialization) Total time : 12.04 seconds
LogLoad : (Engine Initialization) Total Blueprint compile time : 0.11 seconds
LogExternalProfiler : Found external profiler : VSPerf
LogExternalProfiler : Using external profiler : VSPerf
LogWindowsTextInputMethodSystem : Display: IME system now deactivated.
LogOcInput : OculusInput pre - init called
LogHMD : Starting GearVRController plugin
LogAssetRegistry : Asset discovery search completed in 6.6684 seconds
LogCollectionManager : Rebuilt the object cache for 0 collections in 0.000001 seconds(found 0 objects)
LogCollectionManager : Fixed up redirectors for 0 collections in 0.000027 seconds(updated 0 objects)
LogContentStreaming : Texture pool size now 1000 MB
LogSlate : Took 0.000533 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf' (159K)
LogSlate : Took 0.000277 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf' (159K)
LogSlate : Took 0.000127 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf' (159K)
LogContentBrowser : Native class hierarchy updated for 'BlueprintGraph' in 0.0010 seconds.Added 112 classes and 0 folders.
LogSlate : Took 0.000532 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Editor/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-BoldCondensed.ttf' (158K)
Running D : / Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / DotNET / UnrealBuildTool.exe - projectfiles - project = "D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/SurvivalProject.uproject" - game - rocket - progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
LogSlate : Took 0.000132 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Slate/Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf' (155K)
LogHotReload : Recompiling module SurvivalProject...
LogVSAccessor : Warning : Couldn't access Visual Studio
Candidate modules for hot reload :
SurvivalProject
Launching UnrealBuildTool...[D:/ Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / DotNET / UnrealBuildTool.exe SurvivalProject - ModuleWithSuffix SurvivalProject 787 Win64 Development - editorrecompile - FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges - canskiplink "D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/SurvivalProject.uproject"]
Creating makefile for hot reloading SurvivalProject(game project files are newer)
Compiling game modules for hot reload
Parsing headers for SurvivalProjectEditor
Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\SurvivalProject.uproject" "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" - LogCmds = "loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" - Unatten
ded - WarningsAsErrors - installed - FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges
ERROR : 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h' : Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalPro
ject / MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h.conflict'
Error : UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'SurvivalProjectEditor' (platform : Win64, module info : D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code : OtherCompilationError(5)).
CompilerResultsLog : New page : Compilation - 17 Jun 2017 21 : 37 : 31
CompilerResultsLog : Info Creating makefile for hot reloading SurvivalProject(game project files are newer)
CompilerResultsLog : Info Compiling game modules for hot reload
CompilerResultsLog : Info Parsing headers for SurvivalProjectEditor
CompilerResultsLog : Info   Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\SurvivalProject.uproject" "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" - LogCmds = "loginit warning, logexit warning, lo
gdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed -FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges
CompilerResultsLog : Info ERROR : 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h' : Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/
UE4Editor / Inc / SurvivalProject / MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h.conflict'
CompilerResultsLog : Info Error : UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'SurvivalProjectEditor' (platform : Win64, module info : D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code : OtherCompilationError(5)).
LogMainFrame : MainFrame : Module compiling took 5.361 seconds
LogSlate : Took 0.000520 seconds to synchronously load lazily loaded font '../../../Engine/Content/Editor/Slate/Fonts/DroidSansMono.ttf' (77K)
Running D : / Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / DotNET / UnrealBuildTool.exe - projectfiles - project = "D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/SurvivalProject.uproject" - game - rocket - progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
LogHotReload : Recompiling module SurvivalProject...
LogVSAccessor : Warning : Couldn't access Visual Studio
Candidate modules for hot reload :
SurvivalProject
Launching UnrealBuildTool...[D:/ Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / DotNET / UnrealBuildTool.exe SurvivalProject - ModuleWithSuffix SurvivalProject 6365 Win64 Development - editorrecompile - FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges - canskiplink "D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/SurvivalProject.uproject"]
Creating makefile for hot reloading SurvivalProject(game project files are newer)
Compiling game modules for hot reload
Parsing headers for SurvivalProjectEditor
Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\SurvivalProject.uproject" "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" - LogCmds = "loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" - Unatten
ded - WarningsAsErrors - installed - FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges
ERROR : 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h' : Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalPro
ject / MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h.conflict'
Error : UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'SurvivalProjectEditor' (platform : Win64, module info : D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code : OtherCompilationError(5)).
CompilerResultsLog : New page : Compilation - 17 Jun 2017 21 : 39 : 45
CompilerResultsLog : Info Creating makefile for hot reloading SurvivalProject(game project files are newer)
CompilerResultsLog : Info Compiling game modules for hot reload
CompilerResultsLog : Info Parsing headers for SurvivalProjectEditor
CompilerResultsLog : Info   Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\SurvivalProject.uproject" "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" - LogCmds = "loginit warning, logexit warning, lo
gdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed -FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges
CompilerResultsLog : Info ERROR : 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h' : Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/
UE4Editor / Inc / SurvivalProject / MyBlueprintFunctionLibrary.generated.h.conflict'
CompilerResultsLog : Info Error : UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'SurvivalProjectEditor' (platform : Win64, module info : D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code : OtherCompilationError(5)).
LogMainFrame : MainFrame : Module compiling took 4.394 seconds
Running D : / Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / DotNET / UnrealBuildTool.exe - projectfiles - project = "D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/SurvivalProject.uproject" - game - rocket - progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
LogHotReload : Recompiling module SurvivalProject...
LogVSAccessor : Warning : Couldn't access Visual Studio
Candidate modules for hot reload :
SurvivalProject
Launching UnrealBuildTool...[D:/ Program Files / Epic Games / UE_4.16 / Engine / Binaries / DotNET / UnrealBuildTool.exe SurvivalProject - ModuleWithSuffix SurvivalProject 7373 Win64 Development - editorrecompile - FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges - canskiplink "D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/SurvivalProject.uproject"]
Creating makefile for hot reloading SurvivalProject(game project files are newer)
Compiling game modules for hot reload
Parsing headers for SurvivalProjectEditor
Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\SurvivalProject.uproject" "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" - LogCmds = "loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" - Unatten
ded - WarningsAsErrors - installed - FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges
ERROR : 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyActor.generated.h' : Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyActor.genera
ted.h.conflict'
Error : UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'SurvivalProjectEditor' (platform : Win64, module info : D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code : OtherCompilationError(5)).
CompilerResultsLog : New page : Compilation - 17 Jun 2017 21 : 47 : 37
CompilerResultsLog : Info Creating makefile for hot reloading SurvivalProject(game project files are newer)
CompilerResultsLog : Info Compiling game modules for hot reload
CompilerResultsLog : Info Parsing headers for SurvivalProjectEditor
CompilerResultsLog : Info   Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\SurvivalProject.uproject" "D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest" - LogCmds = "loginit warning, logexit warning, lo
gdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed -FailIfGeneratedCodeChanges
CompilerResultsLog : Info ERROR : 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/SurvivalProject/MyActor.generated.h' : Changes to generated code are not allowed - conflicts written to 'D:/Users/Removed/Documents/Unreal Projects/SurvivalProject/Intermediate/Build/Win64/UE4Editor/Inc/Survi
valProject / MyActor.generated.h.conflict'
CompilerResultsLog : Info Error : UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'SurvivalProjectEditor' (platform : Win64, module info : D:\Users\Removed\Documents\Unreal Projects\SurvivalProject\Intermediate\Build\Win64\SurvivalProjectEditor\Development\SurvivalProjectEditor.uhtmanifest, exit code : OtherCompilationError(5)).
LogMainFrame : MainFrame : Module compiling took 4.225 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this in the Unreal Engine forums. I had to change the Solution Configuration in Visual Studio from `Development` to `Development Editor`. I'm now able to add and compile C++ classes.

For anyone who's not sure where to do this, it's the drop down list on the toolbar next to the Play/Run button.